# HTML Table fit screen height

Tags: php, html, css

So this is how my page look like right now (the colors is just to see the containers): [image]

This is my PHP code:

```
<div class="containerrr">
                    <div class="wrapperrr">
                        <center><h4>Leaderboard uke</h4></center>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nr.</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Navn</th>
                                    <th>Salg</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $currentRow = 0;
                                foreach($link->query('SELECT idn,COUNT(*) FROM usr') as $row) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    $currentRow++;
                                    if ($currentRow == 1) {
                                        echo "<td></td>";
                                    }
                                    if ($currentRow == 2) {
                                        echo "<td></td>";
                                    }
                                    if ($currentRow == 3) {
                                        echo "<td></td>";
                                    }
                                    if ($currentRow > 3) {
                                        echo "<td>$currentRow</td>";
                                    }
                                    echo "<td><img  alt='Avatar' class='avatar' src='img.png'/></td>";
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usr WHERE idn='{$row['idn']}'";
                                    $resultt = $link->query($sql);
                                    if ($resultt->num_rows > 0) {
                                         while($roww = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) {
                                             echo "<td>" . $roww['fullname'] . "</td>";  
                                         }
                                    }
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                                ?>
                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.containerrr {
    background-color: red;
    height: 900px;
    position: relative;
}

.containerrr > header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.containerrr > header h1 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapperrr {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em 0 3em;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 2000px;
    
    background-color: blue;
    
    height: 100%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    table-layout: auto;
}
```

I want the table to fit the container(red color). But now I need to scroll down to see all the table data. How can I resize(in this case make it smaller), so all the rows fits the red area, so I don't have to scroll down? What am I missing here?

Comment: set a maximum height on the container and add an overflow y

Comment: Try adding `overflow-y: auto;` to `.containerrr` class.

Comment: @TariqulIslam That makes it fit the red area, but I still have to scroll to see the whole table tho.

Comment: @Amanda That would be a problem, because you may have lots of table rows and it's very difficult to fit these rows into a container having 900px of height.

Comment: Check if second answer on this post can help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34993813/css-fixed-height-on-tr-and-fixed-height-on-table

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` in `containerrr` class.

```css
.containerrr {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: red;
    height: 900px;
    position: relative;
}

.containerrr > header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.containerrr > header h1 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0;
}

.wrapperrr {
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 2em 0 3em;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 2000px;
    
    background-color: blue;
    
    height: 100%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    table-layout: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerrr">
                    <div class="wrapperrr">
                        <center><h4>Leaderboard uke</h4></center>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Nr.</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Navn</th>
                                    <th>Salg</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php
                                $currentRow = 0;
                                foreach($link->query('SELECT idn,COUNT(*) FROM usr') as $row) {
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    $currentRow++;
                                    if ($currentRow == 1) {
                                        echo "<td></td>";
                                    }
                                    if ($currentRow == 2) {
                                        echo "<td></td>";
                                    }
                                    if ($currentRow == 3) {
                                        echo "<td></td>";
                                    }
                                    if ($currentRow > 3) {
                                        echo "<td>$currentRow</td>";
                                    }
                                    echo "<td><img  alt='Avatar' class='avatar' src='img.png'/></td>";
                                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usr WHERE idn='{$row['idn']}'";
                                    $resultt = $link->query($sql);
                                    if ($resultt->num_rows > 0) {
                                         while($roww = $resultt->fetch_assoc()) {
                                             echo "<td>" . $roww['fullname'] . "</td>";  
                                         }
                                    }
                                    echo "<td>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                                ?>
                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: With this I still have to scroll down to see the whole table.